# How to use webpack multiple entries with karma?

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, karma-webpack

I have webpack config with multiple entries:

```
entry: {
  'js/app': ['./css/app/style.scss', './js/app/index.js'],
  'js/vendor': ['./js/vendor/index.js', './css/vendor/index.css'],
  'js/snippets': './js/snippets/index.js'
},
```

and I don't want to hardcode all this paths in karma config.
Just include webpack config and connect all the entries from there:

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');
...
...
files: webpackConfig.entry,
```

but `file` option expect to have an array of strings. 
Is there any ready solution for it? Not to convert object to array manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar setup, here's what worked for me. In the karma config file, for the files just config your tests. For me it was something like this:

```
files: [
  './scripts/vendor/jquery.min.js',
  // any other global dependency
  './scripts/**/*.spec.js'
]
```

**edit**

Because of how webpack works, you don't need to add your project files in the karma configuration. Just by the fact that your test will import/require the test subject file, webpack will bundle it and the test will run.

**endedit**

Then in the preprocessors section:

```
preprocessors: {
  './scripts/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack']
},
```

Finally, I have imported the webpack configuration:

```
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
```

And using the [karma-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-webpack) plugin I added a webpack section as follows:

```
webpack: {
  devtool: webpackConfig.devtool,
  resolve: webpackConfig.resolve,
  module: webpackConfig.module,
  externals: Object.assign({}, webpackConfig.externals, {
    chai: 'chai'
  })
},
```

Comment: and how do you include project files/build?

Comment: I imagine that in your tests you're importing/requiring the project files, so webpack will take care of that.

Comment: could I also ask you to show example of dependancies that you import into your test file? 

| because before when I test with karma I specified all project files in karma config

Comment: If you have external dependencies, you can add them to your files config, for instance I have a global dependency, on jquery, so I add that as well. I'll update the example. But that is as simple as adding the dependencies in the correct order into the files array

Comment: looking forward for you update. your answer already helped a lot! thank you